# Move address to register by using the indexed addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing, indexed

Is it possible to calculate an address by using the indexed addressing mode syntax and store it into a register? Something like the following (wrong) expression (in AT&T assembly syntax):

```
movl $dataarray(,%edi,8), %eax
```

I know that the indexed addressing mode can be used to move data:

```
movl dataarray(,%edi,8), %eax
```

However, in this case, what I want to do is to store the **address** of the element of `dataarray` indexed by `%edi` into the `%eax` register.

Comment: Do you mean something like the `lea` instruction?

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, indeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46194916/move-address-to-register-by-using-the-indexed-addressing-mode#comment79352153_46194916), the `lea` instruction can be used for that purpose:

```
leal dataarray(,%edi,8), %eax
```

This way, the *address* (and **not** the *value at that address*, as it occurs with the `mov` instruction) is computed and stored into the `eax` register.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and explanation